# Can Anyone explain in details that how magento2 cache working?

Tags: magento2, cache

Actually i have modified one file from cache directly in magento2

> pub/static/_cache/merged/528a5a59b09a5ecbef1a.min.css

After that i have run all the commands setup:upgrade

setup:static-content:deploy and cache:flush and cache:clean

still my changes remaining on server.

Can you please tell me how all the caches working?

Comment: are you using any rides cache like that in your server? cdn cache something like?

Comment: op cache @NagarajuKasa

Comment: _cache folder used when you have  merged css from admin panel.
so you have to un-merge it first.
or may be you have used server cache like redis or memcache, opcache like.